# Direct the [director]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The wikiless [director](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/director) has become way, way too ambiguous. The very first page in its `newest` tab has questions that use it to refer to

- [Adobe Director](http://www.adobe.com/products/director.html) (for Shockwave questions)
- [Flatiron Director](https://github.com/flatiron/director)
- [Corona Director Class](http://forums.coronalabs.com/forum/540-director-class/)
- Real-life movie directors

et cetera.

As the majority of the questions in the tag are about Adobe Director, I propose that its tag wiki be changed appropriately and all questions unrelated to Adobe Director be un-tagged and, if possible, re-tagged.

Comment: I'd create a new `adobe-director` class, retag what's clearly on that topic, remove the `director` tag from everything else. With 55 posts that's not that many and the non-adobe-director uses cannot be numerous enough to warrant separate tags.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: that may be a good option!

Comment: Real life movie directors *and* related to programming? Questions about how HAL was programmed?

Comment: @Jongware: no, homework question with the assignment having something about movie directors in it =)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've created [adobe-director](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-director), gave it a minimal wiki page and retagged posts that are clearly about the topic. Please do review the wiki text, I probably got something wrong.

I've voted to close the following questions (retagged as needed):

General computing, not programming:

- <del>[How to make Windows Flash games run on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397302/how-to-make-windows-flash-games-run-on-linux)</del>

Professional network and server setup:

- <del>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883497/nested-directors-in-varnish</del>

Recommendation requests:

- <del>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565879/what-is-the-best-free-as-in-beer-foss-would-be-good-as-well-replacement-for-m</del>
- <del>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205233/should-i-learn-flash-or-director</del>

The remaining uses of [director](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/director) where not really numerous enough to deserve their own tags; there was one testing library with the word *director* in the name, some misspellings (directory is not the same thing as director) and a few uses of a *director* concept in three unrelated frameworks (all involving different programming languages).

I didn't think the 10 questions about the Corona Director class that used [director](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/director) deserved a separate tag; if someone disagrees you'd create a new tag for [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcorona%5D+director+is%3Aq); there may be a case for them.

The tag is now empty and will be deleted with the next zombie tag reaping round.